# Is there a type structure for wcf generated traces?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, trace

I want to set a custom trace listener for my wcf service that will filter the huge quantity of generated traces to retain only meaningful traces according to my needs. 
My question is therefore:

Is there a type structure or a class hierarchy for generated Traces?

My idea is to filter Traces according to their underlying type instead of dealing with the string object provide by the methods Write(string msg) and WriteLine(string msg) of the custom trace listener.

Thanks for help.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/64119e1f-6d7c-4093-b27a-1cadf81aa43a

Comment: @hugh Does it means that there is no possible structure for wcf generated traces?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like it...

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/64119e1f-6d7c-4093-b27a-1cadf81aa43a

**UPDATE** (in response to comment)

It means that there is a structure, however the explicit definition of that structure has not been made available by Microsoft in the form of a XSD.

A possible approach would be to generate an XSD based off one or more sample trace files. You can use xsd.exe to do this.

However this approach is haphazard at best as you cannot be sure your end result will cater for all possible future trace files.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest either [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) or [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/). Functionality is really similar. They both have wide range of destination for logs, but if you want to have some custom destination with some custom functionality you can do this.